# Mule Exceptional Use Case

Tags: mule

I have a mule router all router that routes a message from a file inbound endpoint (Source A) to multiple outbound endpoints(Destination B,C,D,E,F) ( most of these are file based endpoints or drop offs). I use the fork-join pattern using a router and aggregator. This works fine , in case of an error i have a global exception handler using the Mule Reference Exception strategy.I log the exception in the error flow and also alert the user via email. My issue is once i route the message and if any of my subflows (A-D) fail i need to trigger only the failed flow (A-D). But my issue is if  i put the message in the source folder and trigger all sub flows (A-B,A-C,A-D,A-E,A-F). Can i trigger only  only the failed flow (A-D).
Any design suggestions how i can improve is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a flow reference you can separate your connection to choices on all router, thus it becomes separate and hence you could call the flow/subflow(which you are calling and choose between flow or subflow based on your requirement and suitability) from the exception flow or a java program in your exception flow